# Add Promotional Banner to a Specific Page of a Collection on Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

We are using Shopify and would like to be able to add different promotional banners to specific collection pages. For example, have promo banner #1 only show on page 3 of Collection (A) and promo banner #2 only show on page 5 of Collection (B). Is this possible? If so, how could this be easily managed?

Comment: Need more and clear requirements to purpose solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Online store, themes, actions --> edit code. From there search "theme.liquid" and edit in the following code for each collection:

```
{% if collection.handle == "item1" %}
<div id="item1-banner">
    Collection A!
</div>
{% endif %}
```

If you are wanting to use images, then simply use:

```
{%if collection.handle == "item1"%}
<img src="item1banner.jpg" />
{% elseif collection.handle =="item2" %}
<img src="item2banner.jpg" />
{% else %}
<img src="item3banner.jpg" />
{% endif %}
```